# Is there any event FireTV app receive? when TV turned off

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

Is there any event my App on FireTV can receive, when app is in foreground and user turn off TV (FireTV is on and app is in foreground).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen for the [AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY) event which will tell you that you have lost the HDMI connection and so should pause or mute the audio.

[This](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-sdk-frequently-asked-questions) is a very good reference for some of the more obscure FireTV SDK questions.